# How reload @RefreshScope bean in singleton bean - BeanFactory.getBean not working

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

I need certain configuration values updated/ refreshed during runtime.
While i am able to refresh them i am not able to update the configuration bean in a singleton scope.

Here is the config bean:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "refreshable")
@RefreshScope
public record RefreshableProperties(
        Optional<String> valueOne,
        Optional<Integer> valueTwo
) {
}
```

Here is the controller that has an endpoint to show current values and one to refresh them:

```
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MainController {

    private final BeanFactory beanFactory;

    private final ContextRefresher contextRefresher;

    private final RefreshScope refreshScope;

    @GetMapping("/current")
    public String getCurrent() {
        return loadCurrent().toString();
    }

    @GetMapping("/refresh")
    public String refresh() {
        contextRefresher.refresh();//this works - actuator/env now returns refreshed values
        refreshScope.refreshAll();
        return loadCurrent().toString(); // returns old values
    }

    private RefreshableProperties loadCurrent() {
        return beanFactory.getBean(RefreshableProperties.class);
    }

}
```

After i call my refresh endpoint the values are correctly refreshed - i can check with `actuator/env` but the response of the method still shows the old values.

As you see i tried `refreshScope.refreshAll();` as well as using BeanFactory to acquire a fresh? instance of my config.

What is also working is loading the properties from environment:

`environment.getProperty("refreshable.valueOne")`

But i want a refreshed instance of my configuration class,

so how to refresh the bean correctly to have the new values?